# Drupal vhost file not displaying website content

Tags: drupal, virtualhost

I have used virtualhost file in drupal to create multiple sites under one server. Also to remove /drupal from the url.

ex: 202.45.198.98/drupal this is how my URL looks like when ever I visit my website

After creating new Virtual host file for my website, I can see my website without /drupal in url.

Now the problem only the first page is loaded I mean some matter but not images, drupal template or any other links.

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName mysite

DocumentRoot /var/www/drupal
<Directory /var/www/drupal/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/drupal/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/">
    AllowOverride All
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: check your html, where the drupal installation is looking for it css? also check the config file, maybe you find something there in the settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the settings.php inside sites/default folder. You will see a line something like --

```
# $base_url = 'http://www.example.com';  // NO trailing slash!
```

Remove the hash at the start & update the URL with the current URL you have for the drupal instance. Most probably you will solve your problem if your connection setting is correct at the same settings.php file (DB name, server name, username & password).

If you find problem due to clean URL in logging in then you may have to put manual path for logging in as admin, which will be --

```
YOUR_BASE_URL/?q=user/login
```

If you want to disable clean URL then you can write a extra line in your settings.php --

```
$conf = array(
  'clean_url' => 0,
);
```

Have nice drupling :)

Comment: Thank you for your post. I still experience the same problem, I have changed it in both the files default.php and deffault.settings.php

Comment: Your setting file should be settings.php not default.php. If this file name doesn't exists at the location sites/default then please copy paste default.settings.php & rename it with "settings.php"

Comment: I followed your steps, still I experience the same issue.